# Launch a website through button click in excel

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an mvc app which is integrated to excel workbook. I have a "Launch" button in excel which on click should launch the following website:

http://students/SubmitComments/

Here is my controller action:

```
public ActionResult StudentComment(string sid)
{

    SubmitCommentViewModel model = new SubmitCommentViewModel ();
    model.sid = sid;

    TempData["model"] = model;

    return View(model);
}
```

Here is my view:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#"
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<STU.Models.StudentCommentViewModel>" 
%>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Student Comments
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageName" runat="server">
    Student Comments</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
 <form id="Form1" method="post" action="/Student/StudentCommentEmail/">
    <label>
        Run Number: <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Id) %>
    </label>
     <br />
    <br />
   <textarea name="comment" cols="40" rows="5">
    Enter comments here...
    </textarea><br/><br/> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comments" /><br />
     </form>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to do? Show the data in Excel? Why not just hyperlink to it?

Comment: @vcsjones When "Launch" is clicked in excel it does trigger the controller action, but never displays the view. When I manually debug in Visual Studio and type in the web address then I am able to see the view, just not when it is launched from excel

Answer (score 0):

You need to host your website somewhere. http://students/SubmitComments/ is not a valid url. You can't link your excel workbook to your Visual Studio hosted site. That only works within Visual Studio. Unless you setup Visual Studio to work with IIS Express.

If you want others to use this Excel workbook then you will have to host your mvc site somewhere that is publically, or at least internally accessible.